# How to find markov blanket for a node?

Tags: python, weka, markov, rweka, markov-models

I want to do feature selection using markov blanket algorithm. I am wondering is there any API in java/weka or in python to find the markov blanket .

Consider I have a dataset. The dataset has number of variables and one one target variable. I want to find the markov blanket of the target variable.

Any information would be appreciated

Comment: Even I'm looking for the same. Any help!!

Answer (score 3):

1. Find all parents of the node
2. Find all children of the node
3. Find all parents of the children of the node

These altogether gives you the Markov blanket for a given node.